# WriteUTF only works every 2nd time

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble with a simple Java server, client application.
Basically the topics says it all: when I do a writeUTF on the server side it only sends every 2nd time it's being executed.
For an example:

Server:

```
public class Server {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server     = new ServerSocket(7777);
            Socket client           = server.accept();
            DataOutputStream out    = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
            DataInputStream in      = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
            while(true) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    out.writeUTF("Test" + i);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And client:

```
public class Client {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket client           = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
            DataInputStream in      = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream out    = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));

            while(in.readUTF() != null) {
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And the output in the console looks like this:

Test1
Test3
Test5
Test7
Test9
Test11

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: You are discarding every second string you read. ;)

Comment: BTW: readUTF() will never return `null`. It will throw an IOException if the end of file is reached or an error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're discarding data on your client.

When you check `while(in.readUTF() != null)`, you're reading an entry from the stream every time to see if it's non-null.  Then you **discard this value, and read a new one** within the loop.  (As well as losing values, this has the bug that with an odd number of total values, the while condition will evaluate to true but the next call to `readUTF()` would return null within the loop.)

To fix this, you should read the value to a variable, and test this before using it - something like the following:

```
String value;
while((value = in.readUTF()) != null) {
     System.out.println(value);
}
```

If you don't like the assignment and nullity check as a single expression, you can instead assign `value = in.readUTF()` initially and at the end of every loop, but personally I find this more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
        while(in.readUTF() != null) {
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        }
```

throws away every second string it reads. You read one string while testing for end of file, discard it, then read another one and print it.

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming the data in the while loop evaluation here:

```
  while(in.readUTF() != null) {
      System.out.println(in.readUTF());
  }
```

Try this instead:

```
  String line;
  while( ((line = in.readUTF()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your socket in UTF-8

you only need to add "UTF-8" in BufferedWriter and BufferedReader's contstructor

here is the sample

```
this.basicReader =   this.Client.getInputStream();
this.basicWriter =   this.Client.getOutputStream();
this.Reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(basicReader,"UTF-8"));
this.Writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(basicWriter,"UTF-8"));
```

how to send data

```
this.Writer.write("data"+"\r\n");
this.Writer.flush();
```

and your main problem is your client didnt respond a msg when your client receive a msg

```
server to client
client to server
server to client
```

like this, try it.